# How to expose lightning-primitive elements for embedding into LWC HTML files of Salesforce Platform

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am customising LWC `<lightning-datatable/>` for a version for my company. I have been successful importing and extending LightningDatatable in a local app generated by `create-lwc-app`.

ie.

```
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import datatable from './datatable.html`; // copied lightning-datatable component from installed package of https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components

export default class DcxDataTable extends LightningDatatable {
  render() {
     return datatable;
  }
}
```

The problem is that I would like to use this custom lightning-datatable component for Salesforce Platform, but there are dependencies of `<lightning-primitive-datatable-*/>` components that not available for some parent components in the platform, and I am trying to understand why these primitive components are available in some components only, but not all.

Firstly, I'm trying to find where the repository would be for the npm lightning-base-component package, so I could possibly fork the repo instead of making a copy of the package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components

Once lightning-base-components package is installed, there are options to expose these primitive components in the package.json of the lighting-base-component package, which would make lightning-primitive elements available for use by the copied `./datatable.html` template.

```
{
  "lwc": {
      "expose": [
          "lightning/primitiveCellCheckbox",
          "lightning/primitiveCellFactory",
          "lightning/primitiveDatatableStatusBar",
          "lightning/primitiveDatatableIeditPanel",
          "lightning/primitiveDatatableLoadingIndicator",
          "lightning/primitiveHeaderFactory",
      ]
  }
}
```

However, I almost thought that exposing these components was going to not be possible for Platform applications, and that I would have to create `<c-primitive-datatable-* />` component versions myself. To test out that assumption, I deployed `<lightning-primitive-datatable-loading-indicator></lightning-primitive-datatable-loading-indicator>` outside of the lightning-datatable definition. To my surprise, I was able to embed it in one component, but not in another component. When I try to deploy the component to one page, it deploys and is seen. But when I deploy using another component, I get a deployment error saying, 'No MODULE named lightning:primitiveDatatableStatusBar found'. For the component that deployed successfully with the embeded lightning-prlmitive component, I am able to see the component fine. But as I tried to embeded it the same way into another component, I get the no module found error trying to deploy to a sandbox.

[image]

So I'm trying to understand either how:

1. explicitly expose <lightning-primitive-datatable-* /> components for the Salesform Platform, so I can deploy and use in all components, instead of some.
2. or understand why it works in some components, so I can configure other components that can use these primitive components.
3. or chalk it up as a runtime fluke, and convert all `<lightning-primitive-datatable-*/>` components into local `<c-primitive-datatable-*/>` components

Any insights or possible cases are appreciated. Thank you.

ref of ./datatable.html from https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components

```
<template>
    <span aria-live="polite">
        <span class={computedAriaLiveClassForNavMode}
            >{ariaLiveNavigationModeText}</span
        >
        <span class={computedAriaLiveClassForActionMode}
            >{ariaLiveActionModeText}</span
        >
    </span>
    <div
        lwc:dom="manual"
        class="dt-width-observer"
        style="width: 100%; height: 0px"
    ></div>
    <div class="dt-outer-container" style="height: 100%; position: relative">
        <lightning-primitive-datatable-iedit-panel
            data-iedit-panel="true"
            visible={state.inlineEdit.isPanelVisible}
            row-key-value={state.inlineEdit.rowKeyValue}
            col-key-value={state.inlineEdit.colKeyValue}
            edited-value={state.inlineEdit.editedValue}
            column-def={state.inlineEdit.columnDef}
            is-mass-edit-enabled={state.inlineEdit.massEditEnabled}
            number-of-selected-rows={state.inlineEdit.massEditSelectedRows}
            onieditfinished={handleInlineEditFinish}
            onmasscheckboxchange={handleMassCheckboxChange}
        ></lightning-primitive-datatable-iedit-panel>
        <div
            class={computedTableContainerClass}
            onscroll={handleHorizontalScroll}
            style={scrollerXStyles}
        >
            <div
                class="slds-scrollable_y"
                onscroll={handleVerticalScroll}
                style={computedScrollerStyle}
            >
                <table
                    class={computedTableClass}
                    role={computedTableRole}
                    style={computedTableStyle}
                    onkeydown={handleTableKeydown}
                    onclick={handleCellClick}
                    onfocusin={handleTableFocusIn}
                    onfocusout={handleTableFocusOut}
                    aria-label={ariaLabel}
                    aria-labelledby={ariaLabelledBy}
                    aria-rowcount={ariaRowCount}
                >
                    <template if:false={hasValidKeyField}>
                        <!-- empty since keyField wasn't provided -->
                    </template>
                    <template if:true={hasValidKeyField}>
                        <thead class={computedTableHeaderClass}>
                            <tr
                                class="slds-line-height_reset"
                                onprivateresizestart={handleResizeStart}
                                onprivateresizeend={handleResizeEnd}
                            >
                                <template
                                    for:each={state.columns}
                                    for:item="def"
                                    for:index="colIndex"
                                >
                                    <th
                                        style={def.style}
                                        scope="col"
                                        tabindex={def.tabIndex}
                                        aria-label={def.ariaLabel}
                                        aria-sort={def.sortAriaLabel}
                                        key={def.colKeyValue}
                                    >
                                        <template if:true={def.fixedWidth}>
                                            <lightning-primitive-header-factory
                                                style={def.style}
                                                def={def}
                                                dt-context-id={privateDatatableId}
                                                key={def.colKeyValue}
                                                row-key-value="HEADER"
                                                col-key-value={def.colKeyValue}
                                                has-focus={def.hasFocus}
                                                column-width={def.columnWidth}
                                                col-index={colIndex}
                                                sortable={def.sortable}
                                                sorted={def.sorted}
                                                sorted-direction={def.sortedDirection}
                                                show-checkbox={showSelectAllCheckbox}
                                                actions={def.actions}
                                            >
                                            </lightning-primitive-header-factory>
                                        </template>
                                        <template if:false={def.fixedWidth}>
                                            <lightning-primitive-header-factory
                                                style={def.style}
                                                def={def}
                                                dt-context-id={privateDatatableId}
                                                key={def.colKeyValue}
                                                row-key-value="HEADER"
                                                col-key-value={def.colKeyValue}
                                                col-index={colIndex}
                                                resizable={hasResizebleColumns}
                                                sortable={def.sortable}
                                                sorted={def.sorted}
                                                sorted-direction={def.sortedDirection}
                                                has-focus={def.hasFocus}
                                                column-width={def.columnWidth}
                                                resizestep={state.resizeStep}
                                                actions={def.actions}
                                            >
                                            </lightning-primitive-header-factory>
                                            <div>
                                                <input
                                                    placeholder="query here"
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                        </template>
                                    </th>
                                </template>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody style={computedTbodyStyle}>
                            <template
                                for:each={renderedRows}
                                for:item="row"
                                for:index="rowIndex"
                            >
                                <tr
                                    class={row.classnames}
                                    onkeydown={handleTrRowKeyDown}
                                    key={row.key}
                                    data-row-key-value={row.key}
                                    aria-selected={row.ariaSelected}
                                    aria-level={row.level}
                                    aria-expanded={row.isExpanded}
                                    aria-setsize={row.setSize}
                                    aria-posinset={row.posInSet}
                                    tabindex={row.tabIndex}
                                >
                                    <template
                                        for:each={row.cells}
                                        for:item="cell"
                                    >
                                        <template if:true={cell.isCheckbox}>
                                            <td
                                                class={cell.class}
                                                role="gridcell"
                                                tabindex={cell.tabIndex}
                                                data-label={cell.dataLabel}
                                                key={cell.colKeyValue}
                                            >
                                                <lightning-primitive-cell-checkbox
                                                    dt-context-id={privateDatatableId}
                                                    has-focus={cell.hasFocus}
                                                    data-label={cell.dataLabel}
                                                    key={cell.key}
                                                    row-key-value={row.key}
                                                    col-key-value={cell.colKeyValue}
                                                    row-index={rowIndex}
                                                    type={row.inputType}
                                                    is-selected={row.isSelected}
                                                    is-disabled={row.isDisabled}
                                                >
                                                </lightning-primitive-cell-checkbox>
                                            </td>
                                        </template>
                                        <template
                                            if:true={cell.isDataTypeScope}
                                        >
                                            <th
                                                class={cell.class}
                                                style={cell.paddingStyle}
                                                aria-selected={cell.ariaSelected}
                                                aria-readonly={cell.ariaReadOnly}
                                                scope="row"
                                                tabindex={cell.tabIndex}
                                                data-label={cell.dataLabel}
                                                key={cell.colKeyValue}
                                            >
                                                <lightning-primitive-cell-factory
                                                    types={privateTypes}
                                                    aria-selected={cell.ariaSelected}
                                                    data-label={cell.dataLabel}
                                                    alignment={cell.alignment}
                                                    has-error={cell.hasError}
                                                    has-focus={cell.hasFocus}
                                                    column-label={cell.dataLabel}
                                                    column-type={cell.columnType}
                                                    column-sub-type={cell.columnSubType}
                                                    wrap-text={cell.wrapText}
                                                    wrap-text-max-lines={cell.wrapTextMaxLines}
                                                    key={cell.columnType}
                                                    row-key-value={row.key}
                                                    col-key-value={cell.colKeyValue}
                                                    value={cell.value}
                                                    icon-name={cell.iconName}
                                                    icon-label={cell.iconLabel}
                                                    icon-position={cell.iconPosition}
                                                    icon-alternative-text={cell.iconAlternativeText}
                                                    editable={cell.editable}
                                                    display-read-only-icon={cell.displayReadOnlyIcon}
                                                    type-attribute-0={cell.typeAttribute0}
                                                    type-attribute-1={cell.typeAttribute1}
                                                    type-attribute-2={cell.typeAttribute2}
                                                    type-attribute-3={cell.typeAttribute3}
                                                    type-attribute-4={cell.typeAttribute4}
                                                    type-attribute-5={cell.typeAttribute5}
                                                    type-attribute-6={cell.typeAttribute6}
                                                    type-attribute-7={cell.typeAttribute7}
                                                    type-attribute-8={cell.typeAttribute8}
                                                    type-attribute-9={cell.typeAttribute9}
                                                    type-attribute-10={cell.typeAttribute10}
                                                    type-attribute-21={cell.typeAttribute21}
                                                    type-attribute-22={cell.typeAttribute22}
                                                >
                                                </lightning-primitive-cell-factory>
                                            </th>
                                        </template>
                                        <template if:true={cell.isDataType}>
                                            <td
                                                class={cell.class}
                                                style={cell.paddingStyle}
                                                aria-selected={cell.ariaSelected}
                                                aria-readonly={cell.ariaReadOnly}
                                                role="gridcell"
                                                tabindex={cell.tabIndex}
                                                data-label={cell.dataLabel}
                                                key={cell.colKeyValue}
                                            >
                                                <lightning-primitive-cell-factory
                                                    types={privateTypes}
                                                    aria-selected={cell.ariaSelected}
                                                    role="gridcell"
                                                    data-label={cell.dataLabel}
                                                    alignment={cell.alignment}
                                                    has-focus={cell.hasFocus}
                                                    has-error={cell.hasError}
                                                    column-label={cell.dataLabel}
                                                    column-type={cell.columnType}
                                                    column-sub-type={cell.columnSubType}
                                                    wrap-text={cell.wrapText}
                                                    wrap-text-max-lines={cell.wrapTextMaxLines}
                                                    key={cell.columnType}
                                                    row-key-value={row.key}
                                                    col-key-value={cell.colKeyValue}
                                                    value={cell.value}
                                                    icon-name={cell.iconName}
                                                    icon-label={cell.iconLabel}
                                                    icon-position={cell.iconPosition}
                                                    icon-alternative-text={cell.iconAlternativeText}
                                                    editable={cell.editable}
                                                    display-read-only-icon={cell.displayReadOnlyIcon}
                                                    type-attribute-0={cell.typeAttribute0}
                                                    type-attribute-1={cell.typeAttribute1}
                                                    type-attribute-2={cell.typeAttribute2}
                                                    type-attribute-3={cell.typeAttribute3}
                                                    type-attribute-4={cell.typeAttribute4}
                                                    type-attribute-5={cell.typeAttribute5}
                                                    type-attribute-6={cell.typeAttribute6}
                                                    type-attribute-7={cell.typeAttribute7}
                                                    type-attribute-8={cell.typeAttribute8}
                                                    type-attribute-9={cell.typeAttribute9}
                                                    type-attribute-10={cell.typeAttribute10}
                                                    type-attribute-21={cell.typeAttribute21}
                                                    type-attribute-22={cell.typeAttribute22}
                                                >
                                                </lightning-primitive-cell-factory>
                                            </td>
                                        </template>
                                    </template>
                                </tr>
                            </template>
                            <template if:true={isLoading}>
                                <tr>
                                    <td
                                        colspan={numberOfColumns}
                                        class="slds-is-relative"
                                    >
                                        <lightning-primitive-datatable-loading-indicator></lightning-primitive-datatable-loading-indicator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </template>
                        </tbody>
                    </template>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <template if:true={showStatusBar}>
            <lightning-primitive-datatable-status-bar
                error={tableError}
                onprivatesave={handleInlineEditSave}
                onprivatecancel={handleInlineEditCancel}
            ></lightning-primitive-datatable-status-bar>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```